# Let $g \in C([0,1])$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Show that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $g \in C([0,1])$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Define the
>    function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $$f(z): =
>  \int_{0}^{1}g(t)e^{tz}dt$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ Show that $f$ is
>    analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.

So far I am pretty stuck, I suspect we can use Morera's theorem to do it. However I lack the idea on how to start. Anyone can give me a good push or point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you evaluate $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^1 g(t) \frac{e^{t(z+h)} - e^{tz}}{h} \, dt$$ directly? You just need to justify pushing the limit inside the integral.

Answer (score 1):

By continuity of $g$ and compactness of $[0,1]$

$$f(z): =
 \int_{0}^{1}g(t)e^{tz}dt =
 \int_{0}^{1}g(t)
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nz^n}{n!}dt\\=  
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n\int_{0}^{1}g(t)\frac{t^n}{n!}dt =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{z^n}{n!} $$
with

$$a_n= \int_{0}^{1}g(t)t^ndt $$

Answer (score 1):

Effective tool is differentiate respect to $\bar{z}$:
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}f(z) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}\int_{0}^{1}g(t)e^{tz}dt  = \int_{0}^{1}g(t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}e^{tz}dt =0$$

Comment: If you are going to omit justification why not just calculate the ordinary derivative $$\dfrac d{dz}f(z) = \dfrac d{dz}\int_{0}^{1}g(t)e^{tz}dt  = \int_{0}^{1}g(t)\dfrac d{dz}e^{tz}dt =\int_0^1 g(t) te^{tz} \, dt$$

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate slightly on how you got the last equality? The last equality equals to 0 part. thanks

Comment: $e^{tz}$ is analytic.